# How to know if an e-mail was received or sent?

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a VBA script to save selected e-mails onto different folders.

Is there a way, without user input, to know if an e-mail was received or sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Sender-related properties of the email item. The [MailItem.Sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3488);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property which returns or sets an [AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry) object that corresponds to the user of the account from which the `MailItem` is sent. Checking that property and comparing to the [Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.accounts?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm778);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) configured in Outlook you may conclude where the message comes from. The `Accounts` collection object contains a set of `Account` objects representing the accounts available for the current profile. The purpose of the `Accounts` collection object and the `Account` object is to allow the enumeration of `Account` objects in a given profile, the identification of the type of an `Account`, and the use of a specific `Account` object to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

The only more or less reliable way is to check if `MailItem.ReceivedByXYZ` properties (such as `ReceivedByEntryID`) are set. They seem to be only present on the received messages. But I have seen cases where it  was present on the sent messages.

You can check first if the parent folder is Inbox or Sent Items by comparing the current folder's entry id with the entry id of a folder received from `Store.GetDefaultFolder` using `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`. If that fails, check on a `ReceivedByXYZ`  property.